# How to set a property after animating it with a storyboard in pure xaml (no code-behind)

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, properties, setter

I'm looking for a way to set a `Property` after it was animated, in pure `xaml`.

[Msdn has an example of how to do that in `xaml` + `codebehind` :](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493(v=vs.110).aspx)

XAML:

```
<Button
    Content="Animate and Then Set Example 1">
    <Button.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="Button1BackgroundBrush"
        Color="Red" />
    </Button.Background>
    <Button.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
        <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="Button1BackgroundBrush"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
            From="Red" To="Yellow" Duration="0:0:5"
            FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
            Completed="setButton1BackgroundBrushColor" />
        </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

C#:

```
private void setButton1BackgroundBrushColor(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1BackgroundBrush.Color = Colors.Blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case you could add another `ColorAnimation` and delay it appropriately via its `BeginTime` property, like so:

```
<Storyboard>
    <ColorAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="Button1BackgroundBrush"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
        From="Red" To="Yellow" Duration="0:0:5" />
    <ColorAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="Button1BackgroundBrush"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
        To="Blue" Duration="0"
        BeginTime="0:0:5" />
</Storyboard>
```

In more general case, depending on the property type, you could use appropriate animation, if one exists, in analogous way.